# Estimating the maximum frequency of waves on a fixed string?

Tags: waves, material-science

I would like to understand if/how I can estimate an upper limit on the frequency of (standing) waves that can be generated on a string fixed at both ends.

As a first step, the properties of the medium (material of the string) will determine this. In addition to the rigidity, what other properties of the medium, specifically? And how (mathematically) might rigidity (and any properties) affect this? I would expect that for a given amount of energy imparted to the string, the maximum frequency is inversely proportional to the rigidity. But is this a linear relation, or is there a power law?

Additionally I would like to be able to generalize the question to the upper limit of the frequency / lower bound to the wavelength in a (quantized?) medium. How might one proceed with this case?

Finally, if more energy than can be held in a wave of the max frequency is imparted, how might the excess energy get dissipated(?)?

PS: the waves in question are standing waves between one fixed point to the other, not traverse across the thickness of the string.

Comment: It's going to be hard to have wavelengths less that the Planck Length! But seriously, long before you need to worry about quantum mechanics, you will have to treat your "string fixed at both ends" as a 3-dimensional solid object - for example there can be standing waves from one *side* of the string to the other, with wavelengths equal to 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc, times the *diameter* of the string, independent of its length.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant to ask about was standing waves between one fixed point to the other, not traverse across the thickness of the string.